# How to using typescript from npm package

Tags: typescript, npm

I have some "compiler" package that generates some typescript classes.

So, when i tried to run it through npm i got this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

I don't want to compile it to normal JavaScript, because than i will have to compile local files too.

In npm i have:

```
export {startGenerateClientApi} from './api.gen'
export {startGenerateInterfaces} from './i18n.gen'
```

and i just import:

```
import {startGenerateClientApi} from 'nest-client-generator'
```

Than i run it with ts-node

[source code](https://github.com/yantrab/nest-client-generator)

Comment: I'm not sure if ts-node will transpile modules in node_modules. You should distribute javascript instead of the typescript so that people can use it with node.

Comment: But it is for development, for typescript users.

Comment: But you're forcing those users to use ts-node, which they might not want to do or might not be doing. If people use it I would not be surprised if someone complains and ask you to distribute the javascript code. Anyway, looking at the code it looks like ts-node will not compile modules in node_modules (same behaviour as the typescript compiler).

Comment: Also, what do you mean by this? "I don't want to compile it to normal JavaScript, because than i will have to compile local files too."

Comment: Thanks, i finally do it with compile to js.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do that by pointing directly into a typescript file in your package:

```
import {startGenerateClientApi} from 'nest-client-generator/your_path_to_ts_file'
```